# C# Drawing Rectangle On the mouse event

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, windows-forms-designer

I want to draw a rectangle. Thing what I want is that show the user to rectangle on the mouse event.[image]

Like in the image. This is for C# .net Forms application.

Help me to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Thank You
  Yohan

Comment: Is this a rubber-band selection rectangle? Or do you want them to draw a permanent shape outline on the form?

Comment: Yes it is rubber-band selection, not a permanent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that in three steps:

- First check if mouse is pressed down
- If it is then on mouse move event keep initializing the rectangle with new positions while mouse is being dragged
- Then on paint event draw the rectangle. (It will be raised for almost every mouse event, depends mouse refresh rate and dpi)

You can do somthing like this (in your `Form`):

```
public class Form1
{

       Rectangle mRect;

    public Form1()
    {
                    InitializeComponents();

                    //Improves prformance and reduces flickering
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

            //Initiate rectangle with mouse down event
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        this.Invalidate();
    }

            //check if mouse is down and being draged, then draw rectangle
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if( e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mRect = new Rectangle(mRect.Left, mRect.Top, e.X - mRect.Left, e.Y - mRect.Top);
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

            //draw the rectangle on paint event
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
                //Draw a rectangle with 2pixel wide line
        using(Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect);
        }

    }
}
```

later if you want to check if Buttons (shown in diagram) are in rectangle or not , you can do that by checking the Button's region and check if they lie in your drawn rectangle.

Comment: hi this works perfectly, Itried same thing on pictureBox control events but it didn't work. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: it was working but probably it was drawn under the picturebox (on the form)..show me the code you tried.. also check @hans Passant 's answer.. his trick will work every where.

Comment: OK now its working, in my case this.Invalidate(); should be pictureBox1.Invalidate(); Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 4):

The solution by Shekhar_Pro draws a rectangle just in one direction (top to bottom, left to right) if you want to draw a rectangle regardless of the mouse position and the direction of the movement the solution is:

```
Point selPoint;
Rectangle mRect;
void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     selPoint = e.Location; 
    // add it to AutoScrollPosition if your control is scrollable
}
void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
     {
        Point p = e.Location;
        int x = Math.Min(selPoint.X, p.X)
        int y = Math.Min(selPoint.Y, p.Y)
        int w = Math.Abs(p.X - selPoint.X);
        int h = Math.Abs(p.Y - selPoint.Y);
        mRect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);   
        this.Invalidate(); 
     }
}
void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, mRect);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Those blue rectangles look a lot like controls.  Drawing a line on top of a control is hard to do in Winforms.  You have to create a transparent window that overlays the design surface and draw the rectangle on that window.  This is also the way the Winforms designer works.  Sample code [is here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3087655c-bd50-4408-9c55-dd179e442675/).